# Jaxb failed to marshall an annotated class

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

Am using an implementation of `MessageBodyWriter` to marshall all my objects to a file(XML).

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
class Myclass implements MyInterface{
// some private fields
}

interface MyInterface{
//some methods
}
```

I have a `List<MyClass>` objects to save in XML,
But when i call `Marshaller.marshall(object, outputstream)` i got this exception :

> [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshall type "..MyClass" as an element because it is missing @XmlRootElement annotation]

But the thing is that I do have that annotation on `MyClass`. 
Any idea on what is wrong on my marshalling process?

Thanks

Comment: When you call `marshaller.marshall(object, outputstream)`, `object` is an instance of `MyClass` or an instance of `List<MyClass>`?

Comment: object is an instance of MyClass in that case ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can marshall a single instance, right?

```
    MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
    myClass1.setField("value");
    JAXB.marshal(myClass1, writer);
```

But I assume you try to marshall a list? Something like

```
    List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    list.add(myClass1);
    JAXBContext.newInstance(ArrayList.class).createMarshaller().marshal(list, writer);
```

If you want to marshall a list in one XML document you need a wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class MyWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name="child")
    private List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

    public List<MyClass> getList() {
            return list;
    }
...
```

Then it should work, e.g.:

```
    MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
    myClass1.setField("value");
    MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper();
    wrapper.getList().add(myClass1);
    JAXB.marshal(wrapper, writer);
```

results in

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <root>
         <child>
            <field>value</field>
         </child>
    </root>
```